# ¿Cómo obtener los valores de un iList?

Tags: javascript, vb.net, lista

Tengo un `iList` que recibo de `javascript` al controlador y me trae esto:

`["Bueno","Malo","No Aplica","Malo","Bueno","Malo"]`

¿Cómo saco esos valores de ese `iList`, en `vb.net`, ya que se llena dinámicamente?

Comment: Qué has intentado? Te refieres a Visual Basic .net con Windows Forms, WPF, ASP.net (WebForms, MVC)?

Answer (score 1):

Dices que usas VB.NET así que a un objeto de tipo iList puedes accederlo individualmente por el índice. Un ejemplo sería así:

```
Dim p = MetodoQueDevuelveIList()
Dim dato0 = p(0).ToString() 'Esta variable almacenaria el valor "Bueno"
Dim dato5 = p(5).ToString() 'Esta variable almacenaria el valor "Malo"
```

Aunque también podrías recorrerlo con un For Each de esta forma:

```
For Each item In MetodoQueDevuelveIList()
    'Aqui manipulas los datos. La variable item los almacena
    'Y el ciclo los recorrera uno a uno desde el primero hasta el último
Next
```

Te recomiendo que revises la documentación en la [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.collections.ilist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Espero que mi respuesta te sea de ayuda.